# Any tutorials on creating an MVC3 login system without the default ASP.Net membership providers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, membership

I'm looking for a tutorial or small introductory guide on creating a login system for ASP.Net MVC3 without using the default ASP.Net membership provider.

I've created a new MVC3 project with the Internet Application template, and here is the contents of _LogOnPartial.cshtml:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

Is `@User.Identity.Name` part of the membership provider? I'd like to read some more on membership on ASP.Net MVC3, since I already have a database in place with user credentials, I do not need the prapackaged one.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a suggestion for a specific tutorial, but I can say that the User object is not part of the membership provider specifically... if you make a distinction between the Membership provider and the FormsAuthentication provider. In my latest project, I wrote my own users data store and password hashing/validation, but am still using the FormsAuthentication provider to track the user's session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its actually fairly easy to implement custom authentication code in ASP.NET MVC.

In the `LogOn` method of your controller you'll need to call the FormsAuthentication provider after you have authenticated the user's credentials.

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
{
   //Handle custom authorization then call the FormsAuthentication provider

   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(/*user name*/, true);

   //Return view
}
```

After this method call, The User.Identity.Name will be populated, and you can utilize the `AuthorizeAttribute` on your controllers or controller methods.

In the `LogOff` method of your controller you'll call the FormsAuthentication provider again

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

   //Return view
}
```

Comment: I can't find the SignIn method. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: @Sergio Sorry about that, I was using the name I had on my wrapper class accidentally.  Its FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie